# spring failed to convert mybatis Configuration

Tags: xml, spring, mybatis

I tried to use mybatis in my spring project, but I'm wondering one thing: Is  applicationContext need any config to read mybatis.xml?

Here is my xml:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.Ordering.Model" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mapper/*.xml" />
</bean>
```

if I add this config:

```
<property name="configuration" value="classpath:mybatis/mybatis-config.xml" />
```

I will get this message:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration'
```

When I remove it，there is nothing wrong. Do I need any config to convert mybatis.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You configured the wrong type for the `configuration` property, it's not a `Strting`, you should config it with `org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration` as below shows in a inner bean:

```
  <property name="configuration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration">
      ....
    </bean>
  </property>
```

Seems what you really wnat is config the `configLocation` property.

Comment: Thanks. I used `configLocation` instead of `configuration` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have found where the issue is.

remove this config:

```
<property name="configuration" value="classpath:mybatis/mybatis-config.xml" />
```

instead of:

```
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"/>
```